# How to set up Azure ACS (Access Control Services)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-acs

I am new to Azure, Could someone please help me with below queries

1. With IaaS model of development and deployment, how do we integrate Azure ACS(Access Control Services) with a MVC application
2. After authentication user will be registered in MVC applciation for a role say 'admin' or 'user'( admin and user are two groups in ACS). How can we add the registered user to ACS groups programmatic ally using C# code.

Comment: Isn't Azure ACS dead already???

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I am asking about Access control system linked to Azure AD (Active Directory). Are you referring to same?

Comment: Is this the one you're talking about: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_Service?

Comment: Yes i am talking about the same - gaurav

Comment: MS has officially [announced deprecation of ACS](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2013/06/22/azure-active-directory-is-the-future-of-acs/) - [twice](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2015/02/12/the-future-of-azure-acs-is-azure-active-directory/).

Comment: I understand that all those features are moved to azure AD. I am looking to integrate my web application with microsoft idp.